# When using werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(), what is the difference between the terminology of "iterations" and "salt_length"?

Tags: hash, werkzeug

I'm looking at the documentation for werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash() and it mentions that you can specify the salt_length. I understand that the salt_length refers the number of times that the salt is added to the most recent hash and hashed to create a new hash but I'm not sure what the iterations in the documentation refers to. When I print the output of the generate_password_hash method, it returns "pbkdf2:sha256:150000$randomsalt$resultinghash" and I'm assuming the 150000 is the iterations value but I have no idea what this means or how this affects the output.Can someone please explain this to me? And according to the documentation, does this mean that salt_length=8 is the default value?

Answer (score 0):

Salt length is the string length of the random salt
Iterations is the number of times the hash is salted.
Example: let initial hashed password be "hash"
salt be "salt"
salt length is 4.
If i salt the hash 10 times (code below)

```py
hash = "hash"
salt = "salt"
for i in range(0, 10, 1):
    hash = generate_password_hash(f"{salt}{hash}")
salted_hash = hash
```

Iterations is 10 and salt_length is 1
From the [docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/utils/#module-werkzeug.security), the method can be provided as "pbkdf2:[:iterations]"
where method can be md5, sha256, or whatever ones you like. Iterations can be specified in this string too. And yes, 150000 is the iterations. More the salting iterations, It is more difficult to crack the password.